# CSS content-visibility: auto inadvertently hides overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-contain

I'm finally getting around to implementing `content-visibility: auto` in my project to improve render times and general performance. I have a component that has some `inset` on the page but, under certain conditions, I allow the children of the component to overflow out of the container to make the component full bleed.

Now, when I try to add `content-visibility: auto` to this parent component, my component gets cut off at the inset boundary of the parent (it is effectively acting like `overflow: hidden`). I've tried adding `overflow: visible` to my styles which is having no effect at all.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/sam-javed/pen/WNXLdMW) (Uncomment the `content-visibility` line to see the issue; you will need Chrome for `content-visibility` support)

Can I use `content-visibility: auto` without having my overflow hidden?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what [`content-visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility) really does, DO NOT use it!!
For performance, [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain) is really sufficient enough for most cases.

`contain` has already been implemented as a standard in all modern browsers.

Using `content-visibility` will cause some troubles and unexpected results in runtime. Only chromium based browsers treat it as a standard but Firefox and Safari just treat it experimental feature or no support.

If you really want to use `content-visibility`, you have to specify the `contain-intrinsic-size` as well. You can combine `ResizeObserver` + `IntersectionObserver` + `content-visibility` + `contain-intrinsic-size` to make a prefect result, but it is just very stupid that Google made this stupid and buggy `content-visibility`.

The problem in Google's `content-visibility` is that, it does not recognize the rendered size. The browser does not know the correct sizing and thus give you the wrong sizing related to siblings and parent (if it is static/relative position).

The solution is that you use the observer to get the physical size of the element, then you assign the size to custom CSS property, then `contain-intrinsic-size: auto var(--rendered-height)`, then you can use `content-visibility: hidden` or `content-visibility: auto`.

Therefore, please understand `contain` and just use `contain` precisely. `contain: strict` and `contain: content` are common applications.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at English so this answer is through the translate engine. Sorry if you can not understand this answer.
And this answer is includes my speculation.

---

The [`contains-visibility: auto;` document](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain/#valdef-content-visibility-auto) states.

> Turns on layout containment, style containment, and paint containment for the element.

So If you add `contains-visibility: auto;`, you will see that `layout containment` , `style containment` , and `paint containment` are turned on.
Since these containments indicate that outside of the element not render, so I think that `overflow: visible` did not work.

> Can I use content-visibility: auto without having my overflow hidden?

As far as I tried, it could not be done.

Answer (score 0):

> `content-visibility` controls whether or not an element renders its contents at all, along with forcing a strong set of **containment**s

> `auto`: The element turns on layout **containment**, style **containment**, and paint **containment**.

> Paint **containment** essentially clips the box to the padding edge of the principal box. **There can be no visible overflow**. The same things are true for paint containment as layout containment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Containment

Therefore no; overflow will always be hidden when using `content-visibility: auto` (or `contain: content` which is shorthand for `contain: layout style paint`).

---

However, you could use [`contain-intrinsic-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain-intrinsic-size)

```css
contain: size;
contain-intrinsic-size: <width> <height>;
```

...for some small performance gains, and have visible overflow.

> Size containment does not offer much in the way of performance optimizations

---

Emphasis mine.
Some more useful info here: https://web.dev/content-visibility/